# r: Rendering Kable with Shiny in Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, kable

Is there a way to use a render__ function to render a Kable (knitr::) with Shiny in Flexdashboard? I am finding information about general Shiny-Kable rendering, but not specifically with Flexdashboard. Links like this [one](https://rdrr.io/cran/kableExtra/f/vignettes/use_kable_in_shiny.Rmd) are helpful but it would be great to be able to call a render_ function to display the Shiny interactive Kable in my Flexdashboard. Any advice would be awesome!

Thanks!

Stefan

Answer (score 3):

the following is one way of getting this to work in `flexdashboard`.

```
your_reactive_data <- reactive({ your_data })

shiny::renderUI(
    HTML(
        kable(your_reactive_data())
    )
)
```

Comment: Did not work for me, even with `{r results='asis'}`, it still prints just ASCII `|date |country |city |state | ||:----------|:-------|:----------|:-- ....` instead of nice table

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work (for me). However what worked is using `xtable::xtable()` instead of `kable()`. They are produce similar output, and it has the corresponding `renderTable()` function. (as opposed to kable that does not have (yet) a corresponding `renderKable()` function.

```
renderTable({
  your_reactive_data() %>% xtable::xtable()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it (according to [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/use_kable_in_shiny.html) documentation) is just to wrap your code in an empty function:

```
output$mtcars_kable <- function() {
 req(input$mpg)
 mtcars %>%
   mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>%
   select(car, everything()) %>%
   filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
   knitr::kable("html") %>%
   kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
   add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
}
```

My guess is that it's because the `kable_styling` function already generates HTML, you don't need a `render*()` function.